# .htaccess basic out in URL via QRCode

Tags: .htaccess, qr-code

I want to host a static website on Ionos and protect it via basic auth with .htaccess (and htpasswd). For easy access for a selected user audience I want to provide the url and login in credentials as QR-Code: https://username:password@example.com.

[image]

BUT:
On my Android phone when I scan the QR-Code, it is not recognized as link because of the username and password and therefore can't be opened in the browser.
[image]

Is there any way to make this possible? Maybe pass username and password as query params to the webserver (might be a problem as it's an angular app with routing)?

Comment: The cause of the issue apparently is the qrcode reading app you are testing with. _Maybe_ that issue exists with multiple such apps. There is nothing you can do about that on the server side, obviously. But instead of coding username and password in a different way I would recommend to question that approach in general. What sense do credentials make if you store the readable for everyone in a static qrcode? If you _really_ need some form of protection (why?) then take a look at a token instead.

Comment: Many photos on the website which aren't for everyone's eyes, and the target audience is provided with the credentials (in case something goes wrong with the QR code..). The QR Code is only for ease of access.

Comment: As said: _anyone_ can read the credentials from that QRCode. If you _really_ have resources you need to protect, then publishing access credentials in plain view for anyone to read sounds ... contract productive. But maybe that is just my feeling. Since you did not respond to my suggestion I assume you evaluated that approach and decided against it.